# Firebase Authentication updates, but my app still loading

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

guys! For my project the user has to sign up using Firebase Authentication. After successful sign up the app should take the user to the main activity, When I sign up in the app the data goes to firebase authetication. But the problem that occurs is that the progress bar keeps loading and it does nit stop. I do not know why that happens. Here is my code for signing up:

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignUpBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.loginLink.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
        binding.signupBtn.setOnClickListener {
            createAccount()
        }

    }

    private fun createAccount() {
        val fullName=binding.signupFullname.text.toString()
        val userName=binding.signupUsername.text.toString()
        val email=binding.signupEmail.text.toString()
        val password=binding.signupPassword.text.toString()


        when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName)-> Toast.makeText(this, "Name is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)-> Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(email)-> Toast.makeText(this, "Email is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(password)-> Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            else->
            {
                val progressDialog= ProgressDialog(this@SignUpActivity)
                progressDialog.setTitle("SignUp")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...")
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
                progressDialog.show()

                val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if(task.isSuccessful)
                        {
                              saveUserInfo(fullName,userName,email,progressDialog)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            val message=task.exception!!.toString()
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Error : $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            mAuth.signOut()
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
      
   private fun saveUserInfo(fullName: String, userName: String, email: String, progressDialog: ProgressDialog)
   {
       val currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
       val usersRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

       val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
       userMap["uid"] = currentUserID
       userMap["fullname"] = fullName.toLowerCase()
       userMap["username"] = userName.toLowerCase()
       userMap["email"] = email

       usersRef.child(currentUserID).setValue(userMap)
           .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
               if (task.isSuccessful)
               {
                   progressDialog.dismiss()
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Account has been created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

                       .setValue(true)


                   val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                   startActivity(intent)
                   finish()
               }
               else
               {
                   val message = task.exception!!.toString()
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                   progressDialog.dismiss()
               }
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).